# What type of printing technique is this called?

Tags: print-design

Apologies for the poor quality images

[image]
[image]

Comment: What aspect of it are you asking about? The colour, paper, texture, folding, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Are you sure that you are interested in the printing technique, i.e., the method used to put the images and text on the medium? If yes, you probably need to provide more information such as what medium is used (paper, metal, …) and it would be very helpful to have closeups.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a single colour offset litho print, using one "special" ink (ie the turquoise/blue) instead of the normal Cyan / Magenta / Yellow / Black.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. Could be any number of processes:

- one color offset (as Digital Lightcraft mentions) likely using a spot color (Pantone)
- one color screenprint (unlikely but if it's a limited run poster, maybe)
- color laser
- low-fi one color duplicator (such as a Risograph)

Comment: Its unlikely to be a screenprint as the sharpness is too good (and text too small), nor is it likely to be laser as the reflectivity of the printed areas doesn't look right for that.